# Laravel custom artisan command works in terminal with php artisan, but not in code although exit code is 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

In my laravel version 7 application, I have written a custom artisan command for accessing aws cli for pushing files to S3 from laravel.

Artisan command code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class PushFiles extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'S3:push {file}';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Push files';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function handle()
{
    $file = $this->argument('file');
    exec('aws s3 cp '.$file.' s3://custom-bucket');
    echo 'aws s3 cp '.$file.' s3://custom-bucket';
}
}
```

And in my controller I call this command like this:

```
$file_path = '/storage/app/'.$file_name;
$exit_code = \Artisan::call('S3:push',['file' => $file_path]);
return $exit_code;
```

Both $file_name and $file_path variables are assigned relevant values.

And this returns 0 as the exit code which means successful. But file is not copying to the S3 bucket.

File is copying to S3 bucket when executing the command in the terminal as below.

```
 php artisan S3:push <Path to file which is same as $file_path>
```

Furthermore, I tried this code snippet as well to see the terminal output and it shows the exact handler code that I have echo.

```
 dd(\Artisan::output());
```

This is really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

- I would check permissions as first possible issue, e.g. you run command manually on your user permission level, but web server probably runs on different user, typically much more restricted.
- Second thing to check is the AWS access keys. I believe you have set up your working environment, but have you done so for http/web server user?

Comment: For permissions - I have attached my user profile to laravel user group like this. sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .

And for AWS access keys - I don't use access keys since I have attached an IAM role to my EC2 instance which runs this Laravel app. So it implicitly binds keys.